# ¿Cómo logro recorrer este array en PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, array

Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer. Tengo problemas a la hora de recorrer un array, a continuación enseño el código:

```
$productSubCategories = SubCategory::with('products')->where('category_id', 1)->get();
    foreach ($productSubCategories->where('id', 2) as $prueba) { 
            return $prueba;
    }
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:
[image: array devuelto]

El código está bien, es decir, mi idea con relacionar las tablas usando el **ORM de Laravel** está funcionando, sin embargo, estoy confundido de cómo poder recorrer el array por completo, pues al modificar `return $prueba` por `return $prueba->name` únicamente me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: Resultado name]

Nihil, siendo el *name* de la primera parte del array.

Comment: Qué es lo que querés mostrar? El "name" de todos los `productSubcategories`? Si es eso, sacá el `where('id', 2)`, porque te va a mostrar solo un elemento (el único con ese ID).

Comment: Tu `return` es incompatible con lo que dices querer lograr: *estoy confundido de cómo poder **recorrer el array por completo***. Si la idea es recorrer todo el array, no debe haber ningún `return` dentro del `foreach`, pues cuando el código encuentra el `return` se termina. Sea que se trate de recorrer un array con diferentes elementos, o un array de una sola fila con distintas propiedades, debes obtener cada cosa (por ejemplo concatenando) y cuando tengas todo recorrido entonces pones el `return $laVariableConcatenadora;` FUERA del bucle, no dentro.

Comment: Tal y como tienes montada la query la forma de recorrer el array de los productos y no la categoría, sería hacer un : "foreach ($productSubCategories[0]->products as $prueba)", y el return del medio del bucle como ya han comentado hará que solo se muestre el primero, si lo cambias por un var_dump($prueba->name) verás que si que saca todos los productos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que se esta haciendo mas trabajo del que en realidad es necesario en tu código.

Te comento:

Según lo expuesto estás intentando obtener:

- Una subcategoría específica por su id y esa misma subcategoría por el id de la categoría a la que pertenece (*asumiendo que una subcategoría pertenece a mas de una categoría*)
- Obtener los productos asociados a dicha subcategoría

De ser así, entonces esta query:

```
$productSubCategories = SubCategory::with('products')->where('category_id', 1)->get();
```

Puede quedar así:

```
$productSubCategories = SubCategory::with('products')
                                   ->whereCategoryId(1)
                                   ->whereId(2)
                                   ->firstOrFail();
```

Lo anterior entonces te puede estar devolviendo:

- Un objeto y una colección, de los cuales puedes obtener los valores de esta forma:

  ```php
  echo $productSubCategories->propiedad....; //aquí la data de la subcategoría
  foreach($productSubCategories->products as $elemento) {
      $elemento->propiedad.....; //aquí la data de los productos
  }
  ```

Y así nota que no requieres mas que un solo ciclo y puedes quitar ese `where` que pusiste en tu `foreach`

Comment: Está perfecto, pero tengo un pequeño problema. Te pongo en situación, una categoría tiene muchas subcategorías y una subcategoría tiene muchos productos. Partiendo de ahí, lo que busco es mostrar los productos de X subcategoría. Sin embargo, **también quiero mostrar TODOS los productos de todas las subcategorías** Por lo que `->whereId(2)` se elimina de la ecuación y `firstOrFail()` no me sirve, debido a que me muestra solamente una subcategoría y no todas. Debo usar `get()`, pero en este caso sí tendría que anidar un foreach como en la respuesta que hice. ¿Alguna recomendación?

Answer (score 3):

Tu `return` es incompatible con lo que dices querer lograr: *estoy confundido de cómo poder **recorrer el array por completo***.

Si la idea es recorrer todo el array, no debe haber ningún `return` dentro del `foreach`, pues cuando el código encuentra el `return` se termina, interrumpiendo inmediatamente el bucle.

Sea que se trate de recorrer un array con diferentes elementos, o un array de una sola fila con distintas propiedades, debes obtener cada cosa (por ejemplo concatenando) y cuando tengas todo recorrido entonces pones el `return $laVariable;` FUERA del bucle, no dentro.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Declaramos la variable que usaremos para concatenar

$mData="";

#En el bucle usaremos la notación as $k=>$v
#que nos permite obtener cada propiedad => valor

$productSubCategories = SubCategory::with('products')->where('category_id', 1)->get();
foreach ($productSubCategories->where('id', 2) as $k=>$v) 
{ 
    $mData.="$k: $v \n";
}

#Aquí el bucle habrá terminado, todo estará concatenado en $mData
#y entonces ya podrás retornar 

return $mData;
```

OJO: Si no estás en el contexto de una función, tendrías que cambiar:

```
return $mData;
```

por

```
echo $mData;
```

O usar `$mData` para lo que necesites.

Comment: Yo también pensé que debía agregar un `$k=>$v` dentro del foreach, sin embargo, me di cuenta que estaba equivocado puesto que `$k` siempre devolvía únicamente el valor **0**. Agregué la respuesta por si quizá a alguien le sirve.

Comment: @Santiago, dado que has puesto una captura de pantalla y no el texto, no se apreciaba con claridad que había objetos anidados, en cuyo caso tendrías que entrar en un primer nivel para encontrar los otros elementos. De todos modos, creo que lo más sensato es lo que te dice BetaM en su respuesta, puesto que sugiere no sólo una solución, sino también una forma de optimizar el código.

Answer (score 0):

```
$productSubCategories = SubCategory::with('products')->where('category_id', 1)->get();
foreach ($productSubCategories->where('id', 2) as $prueba) { 
        return $prueba;
}
```

Lo único que debe agregar es un foreach anidado, como se muestra a continuación:

```
foreach ($productSubCategories->where('id', 2) as $prueba) {
      foreach ($prueba->products as $productSubCategory) {
        $allProducts[] = $productSubCategory;
      }
    } 
    return $allProducts;
```

De esta manera, `$prueba` ingresa a **products** gracias a `$prueba->products` y logra recorrer cada elemento dentro de él, quedando visualmente de esta manera:
[image: resultado]